# Help with this Elementary $\bf ZF$ Set Theory exercise?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

1. Prove that $x = \emptyset \leftrightarrow x\sim\emptyset$.
2. Prove that $(\exists a)x = \{a\} \leftrightarrow x\sim\{\emptyset\}$.

### For the first one:

"$\rightarrow$"

$x = \emptyset \rightarrow  f(x) = x$ is a bijection from $x$ to $x$, therefore $x$ ~ $\emptyset$.

"$\leftarrow$"

$x\sim\emptyset \rightarrow \exists f:x \longrightarrow \emptyset$ bijection. Let $x\neq\emptyset \rightarrow \exists a\in x$. Since $f$ is onto $\rightarrow f(a) \in \emptyset$ is a contradiction. So, $x = \emptyset$

### For the second one:

I'm kind of lost here. I could construct a function $f:x \longrightarrow \{\emptyset\}$ with $f(a) = \emptyset$ but I don't really know how to continue.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first proof is fine. It is even simpler to say that if $f\colon x\to\varnothing$ is a bijection, then $f\subseteq x=x\times\varnothing=\varnothing$ and so $f=\varnothing$. Since $x=\operatorname{dom}f$, $x=\varnothing$ as well.

For the second one, you are correct. Defining the function $\{\langle a,\varnothing\rangle\}$ and proving it is a bijection will solve one implication; and in the other direction, if $f\colon x\to\{\varnothing\}$ is a bijection use the fact that $f$ is injective to prove that $x$ cannot have more than one element; and since it is surjective it has to have at least one element.

Comment: My problem is when I try to prove is one-to-one.
Let b,c in x = {a}, then b must be equal to c no and f(b) must be equal to f(c). How do I go from f(b)=f(c) to b = c?

Comment: If it wasn't injective... what would have to be the case?

Comment: f(b) = f(c) -> b = c must be true because b = c = a ?

Comment: Yes. That's the gist.